# SELECT distinct count from count(*)

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 Create table t1 (val1 number);

 INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1);
 INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1);
 INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1);
 INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1);


 INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (2);
 INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (2);
 INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (2);
 INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (2);


 INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (3);
 INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (3);
 INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (3);
 INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (3);
 INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (3);
 INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (3);

SELECT val1, count(*) c from t1
Group by val1 order by val1

  VAL1    C
 1    4
 2    4
 3    6
```

I'm looking to do a distinct count on c so my output would look like this:

```
4   2 -- 4 distinct value of c 2 recs
6   1 -- 6 distinct value of 1 recs
```

In my prod area I have a ~19 million recs so this needs to be fast. I was hoping to implements Connor McDonald's last solution in the video below if possible or the hash method.

https://youtu.be/LJZy4oV63ZQ

Comment: I think you cannot use bitmaps or hashes for your query. The bits in the map can only be `0` or `1`, but you want counts of occurence. In other words, you need a map of counters rather than a map of bits. But thanks for pointing to the `BITMAP_COUNT` functions!

Comment: Both Gordons and ismetguzelgun's answers are pretty fast. I've generated a table with 19 million rows of random numbers, and Gordon's answer takes 1.8 seconds, ismetguzelgun's 2.4 secondst.

Comment: Thanks for the help very much appreciated. The new functionality looked interesting  and I wanted to play with it I appreciate your explanation

Comment: Yes, it's certainly worth exploring, thanks again for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery and more aggregation:

```
SELECT cnt, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT val1, count(*) as cnt
      FROM t1
      GROUP BY val1
     ) v
GROUP BY cnt
ORDER BY cnt;
```

Comment: Thanks, works great but can this be done with the bitmap function in 19c, it looks like it's the better method than the subquery. The video is very informative

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way. You can use analytical functions to accomplish your goal.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT COUNT(VAL1), COUNT( *)OVER(PARTITION BY COUNT( VAL1))
FROM T1
GROUP BY VAL1
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: know about the district court and it can be painfully slow. As mentioned I have 19 million rows in my table. I was looking for a bitmap solution as per connor McDonald video that can be made into a generic function and produce the out I specified in my example. Thanks for your response –